# TCP Gateway Spring integration video tutorials

Tags: java, spring, tcp, spring-integration

Are there any video tutorials exist on Spring TCP Gateway Integration, which gives an overview idea about Spring-int TCP gateway including examples? I have gone through youtube and googled as well but couldn't find any video tutorials on the topic. It would be a great help if anyone could share any portals/links which has video tutorials or any tutorials which explain Spring TCP gateway in a simple manner.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of a video but there's [a simple sample app that shows the use of both inbound and outbound gateways to invoke an echo service over TCP](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/tcp-client-server).

It uses the default CRLF to delimit messages; be sure to read the section about (de)serializers in [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#connection-factories).